# Trying to POST form data to mysql database, receiving and error

Tags: php, mysql

Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

The database I am using is my school's server, so I don't have admin rights to it. Could someone shed some light on what my issue may be? I'm certain my credentials work.

Here is my PHP code:

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <?php 
   $servername = "triton.towson.edu";
   $username = "XYZ";
   $password = "XYX";
   $dbname = "XYZ";
   $carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
   $rating = $_POST['rating'];
   $type = $_POST['typesel'];
   $uname = $_POST['uname'];


   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


   $sql = 'INSERT INTO  ctrade1db.survey'.
    '(carrier, rating, type, username) '.
    'VALUES ($carrier, $rating, $type, $uname)';
    mysql_query($sql);

   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
      die('Error: Not added' . mysql_error());
   }
  echo "1 record added";

  mysql_close($con)
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: you're mixing MySQL APIs and also using the wrong variable. then your values will fail and a missing semi-colon

Comment: *oh*, and technically speaking, you're calling the query twice.